# os_defines.h: fatal error: features.h no such file or directory

Tags: c++, cross-compiling

I setted up a cross compiling environment on a Debian 7 for a Beaglebone Black and a Odroid. I used linaro. As framework I use Qt.

All worked fine.

Then I had to flash a newer system on the Beaglebone and forgot to secure the compiled Libs. Luckily I still had the dir with the compiles Libs on my host (the directory with the sources after make). So I just used make install on this directory. The Librarys are now on the Beaglebone.

But when I try to compile the compiler complains a missing features.h. The header is in the expected directory (unter linaro/arm-linux-gnuabihf/libc/usr/include).

While cross-compiling Qt I used the sysroot option but if the compiler searchs on the Beaglebone, there is another features.h (/usr/include).

So the header is there but why does my compiler complain??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, my big fault...

needed to install build-essential on the board