# Cross compile ffmpeg for Tizen

Tags: ffmpeg, cross-compiling, tizen

Im trying to compile ffmpeg for Tizen TV as a static library using toolchains.
This is the script I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
function buildme
{

./configure --prefix=$PREFIX                    \
                --target-os=linux                 \
                --arch=$ARCH                        \
                --cpu=armv7-a                        \
                --enable-runtime-cpudetect          \
                --disable-doc                       \
                --disable-ffmpeg                    \
                --disable-ffplay                    \
                --enable-cross-compile              \
                --enable-optimizations              \
                --disable-ffprobe                   \
                --disable-devices                   \
                --disable-avdevice                  \
                --disable-debug                     \
                --enable-pic                        \
                --disable-shared                    \
                --enable-gpl                        \
                --enable-static                     \
                --sysroot=/path-to-tizen-studio/tools/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-6.2/arm-tizen-linux-gnueabi \
                --cross-prefix=${PLATFORM}/bin/$PLATFORM_PREFIX \
                --extra-cflags="-O3 -std=c++11 -DHAVE_SYS_UIO_H=1 -Dipv6mr_interface=ipv6mr_ifindex -fasm -Wno-psabi -fno-short-enums  -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=300 -fpic $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS"               \
                --enable-asm                        \
                --extra-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/lib -L$PLATFORM/lib -nostdlib" \
                --cc=${CCOMPILER} \
                $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

   make clean
   make  V=1
   make install
}

echo configuring....

PLATFORM=/path-to-tizen-studio/tools/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-6.2
PREFIX='pwd'/thridParty
PLATFORM_PREFIX=arm-linux-gnueabi-
ARCH=arm
CCOMPILER=${PLATFORM}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS="-marm"
buildme

echo end
```

And I obtain this error:

> /path-to-tizen-studio/tools/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-6.2/arm-tizen-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/6.2.1/arm-tizen-linux-gnueabi/bits/os_defines.h:39:22:
> fatal error: features.h: No such file or directory
> #include <features.h>

Answer (score 0):

Instead Tizen `gbs` build would be helpful if we can setup tizen env.

I've verified builds using

- Env: https://docs.tizen.org/platform/developing/building/
- Source code: https://git.tizen.org/cgit/platform/upstream/ffmpeg/

Comment: Or, would you refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374231/os-defines-h-fatal-error-features-h-no-such-file-or-directory and try `sudo apt-get install build-essential` in case cross-compiling is still required ?